# How to resolve symbol lookup error Perl_xs_handshake from lcov

Tags: gcc, cmake, gcov, lcov

I am using CMake to compile a large program. The file structures is seen here:

[Structure pt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUzQh.png)
[Structure pt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm0kv.png)

My goal is to create an lcov coverage report that tells me what portion of the code is run by the tests in
/meshFieldsDev/meshFields/test/

I am using this module: https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake

This is the relevant code in my CMakeLists.txt that runs the module:
[Relevant code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahFDc.png)

To run the code I start by running

```
rm -rf build-meshFields-cuda/
```

from `meshFieldsDev` to blow away the build directory and ensure I have a fresh build directory.

I then run

```
cmake -S meshFields -B build-meshFields-cuda -D meshFields_ENABLE_COVERAGE_BUILD=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

to make a debug build / create the fresh build directory.

Next I `cd` into the build directory, build-meshFields-cuda and run `make` and `make coverage`.

"Make coverage" results in the error:

```
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /opt/scorec/spack/v0154_2/install/linux-rhel7-x86_64/gcc-10.1.0/perl-compress-raw-zlib-2.081-woruhujhcqpsvppu7ox7keagflycc4c7/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Compress/Raw/Zlib/Zlib.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_handshake
```

I am fairly certain I don't have access to files outside my workspace, i.e., I cannot update or install new modules. Here is what we have loaded:

[Loaded modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es2y7.png)

According to similar posts on Stack Overflow, the error results from two different versions of perl being used across modules / compilation. I believe that lcov compiles with `usr/bin/perl` by default and the path for the version of perl we want to use is `/opt/scorec/spack/v0154_2/install/linux-rhel7-x86_64/gcc-10.1.0/perl-5.30.3-tmxduzj6hwvxe6ccra6jg3ec65ltesis/bin/perl`.

We tried reinstalling a bunch of stuff, lcov, gcc, perl and it's modules in hopes that would fix the issue / put them in the same directory. This did not help since while we have lcov installed in `/opt/scorec/spack/v0154_2/install/linux-rhel7-x86_64/gcc-10.1.0/lcov-1.16-5lw4jlj5ignaucfzy4ruons4khzkmzdz/bin/lcov along side perl-5.30.3` it's default is still grabbing from `usr/bin/perl`.

I tried this:
https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov/commit/74bae96e8ef724eb9dbdf126adad17505375e149
to have lcov use the proper version of perl and was met with this error:

[Error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5o9t.png)

I think that this is likely because I don't have access to the higher level in the file system so I can't install or change anything up there. I do not know if there is another way to force it to not use the default.

I also tried running this command after the make (I was told it would use the 5.30.3 version of perl)

```
$ perl -S  lcov -c -d . -o main_coverage.info
```

However it resulted in the same error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here **images** which just represent *textual* information are **discouraged**: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors. Instead, paste **code** and **error message** into the question post as **text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the shebangs in `lcov.perl`, `geninfo.perl`, and `genhtml.perl` are set at install time to the default path, in my case `usr/bin/perl`. This was not the path for the version of perl I wanted to use so I simply changed the shebangs to be the correct path, `/opt/scorec/spack/v0154_2/install/linux-rhel7-x86_64/gcc-10.1.0/perl-5.30.3-tmxduzj6hwvxe6ccra6jg3ec65ltesis/bin/perl`.

This will cause issues in the future if I update the perl in this hardcoded path but I am not permitted to change `usr/bin/perl`.